# Property doesn't exist in collection: BelongsTo Realtion is empty

Tags: php, laravel, collections, eloquent, relationship

I have users and products. Users can save/mark products to see them late on again.

I will post you all of my three models below. I want to access an product which is marked by the user. So, I call `$user->markedProducts->product` which is defined as a `belongsTo` relation. However, I cannot access the property `product` because it's not contained in the collection although I wrote `protected $with = ['product'];` in the `MarkedProduct` model.

My question is, how can I access each product object via the `MarkedProduct` model to print things such as the name, heading and etc. of the product?

Error I get:

```
Property [product] does not exist on this collection instance.
```

User model:

```
class User extends Authenticatable
{
    public function products()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Product');
    }

    public function markedProducts(){
        return $this->hasMany('App\MarkedProduct');
    }
}
```

Product model:

```
class Product extends Model
{

    /**
     * The relationships that should always be loaded.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $with = ['comments'];

    /**
     * Get the user that owns the product.
     */
    public function user()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\User');
    }
}
```

MarkedProduct model:

```
class MarkedProduct extends Model
{
    /**
     * The table associated with the model.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $table = 'products_marks';

    /**
     * The relationships that should always be loaded.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $with = ['product'];

    /**
     * Get the user that owns the comment.
     */
    public function user()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\User', 'user_id');
    }

    /**
     * Get the product that owns the comment.
     */
    public function product()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Product', 'product_id');
    }
}
```

Product migration:

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('products', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->bigIncrements('id');
        $table->unsignedBigInteger('user_id')->index();
        $table->unsignedBigInteger('supplier_id')->index()->nullable();
        $table->unsignedBigInteger('dispatch_country_id')->index()->nullable();
        $table->unsignedBigInteger('product_type_id')->index();
        $table->unsignedBigInteger('post_status_id')->index()->default(4);
        $table->string('slug', 400)->index()->unique();
        $table->string('url', 1000)->nullable();
        $table->string('image_url', 1000)->nullable();
        $table->string('voucher')->nullable();
        $table->timestamp('start_date')->nullable();
        $table->timestamp('end_date')->nullable();
        $table->string('heading');
        $table->text('description');
        $table->integer('price')->nullable();
        $table->integer('old_price')->nullable();
        $table->integer('percentage')->nullable();
        $table->integer('price_off')->nullable();
        $table->boolean('free_shipment')->nullable();
        $table->timestamps();

        $table->foreign('user_id')
            ->references('id')
            ->on('users');

        $table->foreign('post_status_id')
            ->references('id')
            ->on('post_statuses');

        $table->foreign('supplier_id')
            ->references('id')
            ->on('suppliers')
            ->onDelete('set null');

        $table->foreign('dispatch_country_id')
            ->references('id')
            ->on('dispatch_countries')
            ->onDelete('set null');

        $table->foreign('product_type_id')
            ->references('id')
            ->on('product_types');
    });
}
```

User migration:

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->bigIncrements('id');
        $table->string('name')->unique();
        $table->string('email')->unique();
        $table->timestamp('email_verified_at')->nullable();
        $table->string('password');
        $table->rememberToken();
        $table->date('birthday')->nullable();
        $table->integer('follower')->default(0);
        $table->integer('points')->default(0);
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}
```

MarkedProduct migration:

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('products_marks', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->unsignedBigInteger('product_id')->index();
        $table->unsignedBigInteger('user_id')->index();
        $table->timestamps();

        $table->foreign('product_id')
            ->references('id')
            ->on('products')
            ->onDelete('cascade');

        $table->foreign('user_id')
            ->references('id')
            ->on('users')
            ->onDelete('cascade');
    });
}
```

Comment: Sure that all datasets exist and have correct primary <-> foreign key?

Comment: I am quite sure but looks like this could be my error. What do I need to check or post here so you can check it?

Comment: Just added the migrations

Comment: Try this out: ignore MarkedProducts Model. Update `markedProducts` relationship in `user` model. Type `return $this->belongsToMany('App\Product', 'products_marks');` . As far as I understood your case you want to give the users the option to see their marked products, so get them like this: `User::with('markedProducts')...`

Comment: @Commander thank you! It's working. Could you may explain why I don't need a model? Post this as an answer and I will accept and upvote your answer! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nice to read, that I could help you.

### Explanation

As @baceto90 already mentioned, you don't need a MarkedProducts Model, because you have a many-to-many relationship.

- "A user has many marked products"
- "A product is marked by many users"

So, actually you want to receive the `users` `products` or `products` `users` and not `markedProducts` `products`. `products_marks` is simply a joining table, which is used to find all `products` or `users` according to the request. This is not laravel specific, for more information google something like `MySQL joining table many to many`.

Many-to-many relationships in laravel models are defined by writing a method that returns the result of the `belongsToMany` method. To determine the table name of the relationship's joining table, Eloquent will join the two related model names in alphabetical order. You can override this by passing a second parameter to `belongsToMany`.

https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many

### Solution

1. Ignore MarkedProducts Model
2. Update markedProducts relationship in user model. Type return $this->belongsToMany('App\Product', 'products_marks'); .
3. Get `markedProducts` like this: `User::with('markedProducts')`

Hope everything is clear now. If not, just ask.

Answer (score 1):

You dont need model at all for marked products. Just read [many to many](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many) relationship.